# making a function that does stuff to pictureboxes?

Tags: vb.net

```
Function myFunction(ByVal degree1 As PictureBox) As PictureBox
    degree1.Visible = True
    degree1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Standard Pics\waiting3.gif")
    degree1.Location = New Point(locationx, locationy)
    degree1.Size = New Size(51, 51)
End Function
```

I'm very new to making functions in visual basic- anyway, I'm trying to make a function that makes several changes to a picturebox, but it gives me this "Argument not specified for parameter 'degree1' of 'Public Function myFunction(ByVal degree1 As PictureBox) As PictureBox'" error- any possible fixes?

Comment: Is this Visual Basic dot net rather than VBA?

Comment: yeah it is, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following:

```
Sub mySub(ByRef degree1 As PictureBox)
    degree1.Visible = True
    degree1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Standard Pics\waiting3.gif")
    degree1.Location = New Point(locationx, locationy)
    degree1.Size = New Size(51, 51)
End Sub
```

Note the `ByRef` part in Sub() signature - it means that you're directly operating over given `PictureBox` object. This is called "passing argument by reference". You can read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddck1z30.aspx). Oh, and I presume you have your `locationx` and `locationy` variables set somewhere in your code?